# Insert data in specific columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to insert the data obtained from the date column. Columns headers are `date,day,month,year,pcp1,pcp2,pcp3,pcp4,pcp5,pcp6` in the csv file. The columns `day, month, year` are currently empty.

I would like to insert the data obtained from the date by split method into these columns. How can l do that?

Here is an example data in csv file:

```
date    day month   year    pcp1    pcp2    pcp3    pcp4    pcp5    pcp6
1.01.1979               0.431   2.167   9.375   0.431   2.167   9.375
2.01.1979               1.216   2.583   9.162   1.216   2.583   9.162
3.01.1979               4.041   9.373   23.169  4.041   9.373   23.169
4.01.1979               1.799   3.866   8.286   1.799   3.866   8.286
5.01.1979               0.003   0.051   0.342   0.003   0.051   0.342
6.01.1979               2.345   3.777   7.483   2.345   3.777   7.483
7.01.1979               0.017   0.031   0.173   0.017   0.031   0.173
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv

dd=[]
mm=[]
yy=[]
with open('output2.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=("date","day","month","year","pcp1","pcp2","pcp3","pcp4","pcp5","pcp6"), delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
            next(reader)  # skip header row
            x = [row['date'] for row in reader]

for date_str in x:
    day, month, year = date_str.split('.')
    dd.append(day)
    mm.append(month)
    yy.append(year)

csvfile.close()

with open('output2.csv') as f:
    fieldnames = ["date","day","month","year","pcp1","pcp2","pcp3","pcp4","pcp5","pcp6"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for i in range(len(dd)):
        writer.writerow({'day':dd[i]})
    for i in range(len(mm)):
        writer.writerow({'month':mm[i]})
    for i in range(len(yy)):
        writer.writerow({'year':yy[i]})


f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas. You will be able to use most of your code which is not too far from working

```
import pandas as pd    
filename = "test.csv"
data = pd.read_excel(filename)

x = data["date"]
dd=[]
mm=[]
yy=[]

for date_str in x:
    day, month, year = date_str.split('.')
    dd.append(day)
    mm.append(month)
    yy.append(year)

data["day"] = dd
data["month"] = mm
data["year"] = yy

data.to_csv("test2.csv")
```

In test2.csv the day month year is filled. If you do't want to have the index as first row ( I would not) use

```
data.to_csv("test2.csv",index = False)
```

as last lane

Comment: when l try to install a module in python 3.5 ,l get this error :"Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ".l have two version of python 3.5 and 2.7 and it cause this problem l think but l m not able to solve it yet.l tried many things on here as solution but no work. That is why ,without pandas ,l need to solve it.

Comment: I tested it with python 2.7. It works well. I have no experience with python 3.5 so I cannot help you there

Comment: Have you solved your problem about installing modules? I was suprised seeing you accepted my answer

Comment: l tried on my friends pc and it works fine .that is why ,l accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just parse the CSV as follows. This reads all of your rows into a list, and then inserts the date componants into the empty columns.

```
import csv

with open('output2.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    header = next(csv_input)
    rows = list(csv_input)

with open('output2b.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in rows:
        day, month, year = row[0].split('.')
        row[1:4] = [day, month, year]
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
date;day;month;year;pcp1;pcp2;pcp3;pcp4;pcp5;pcp6
1.01.1979;1;01;1979;0.431;2.167;9.375;0.431;2.167;9.375
2.01.1979;2;01;1979;1.216;2.583;9.162;1.216;2.583;9.162
3.01.1979;3;01;1979;4.041;9.373;23.169;4.041;9.373;23.169
4.01.1979;4;01;1979;1.799;3.866;8.286;1.799;3.866;8.286
5.01.1979;5;01;1979;0.003;0.051;0.342;0.003;0.051;0.342
6.01.1979;6;01;1979;2.345;3.777;7.483;2.345;3.777;7.483
7.01.1979;7;01;1979;0.017;0.031;0.173;0.017;0.031;0.173
```

Tested using Python 3.5.2

Comment: when l try it , it gives me that error " day, month, year = row[0].split('.')
IndexError: list index out of range" . l m using Python 3.5.

Comment: For Python 3.5 the file needs to be opened differently, try it now.

Comment: l tried it works with python 2.7 via pervious answer of you. then ,l tried with python 3.5 via new answer and some files ,it gives error :   day, month, year = row[0].split('.') .ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) as l think "date" column ,it must use but according to code,there are many columns that the code try to split.

Comment: I'm guessing your CSV file is not in the expected format, normally it has commas as delimiters. If you added a line such as `print(rows)` you should see something like `[['1.01.1979', '', '', '', '0.431', '2.167', '9.375', '0.431', '2.167', '9.375'], ....`

Comment: Assuming you do have `;` as the delimiter, just add that to the `csv.reader()` line as you had before.

Comment: l corrected after your recommend and it works fine and l did not reliase your corrected answer and l posted mine here combined with your answer.l m so sorry for this and l tried to delete my post .l m not sure if it deleted or not. thanks for your effort and time.